# Issue specifying parameters to 'pstops' in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, popen

Issuing this command from the command line:

```
pdftops -paper A4 -nocenter opf.pdf - | pstops "1:0@0.8(0.5cm,13.5cm)" > test.ps
```

works fine. I tried to convert this to a parameter list for `subprocess.Popen` like this:

```
import subprocess as sp

path = 'opf.pdf'

ps = sp.Popen(
            ["pdftops",
             "-paper", "A4",
             "-nocenter",
             "{}".format(path),
             "-"],
            stdout = sp.PIPE)
pr = sp.Popen(
            ["pstops",
             "'1:0@0.8(0.5cm,13.5cm)'"],
            stdin = ps.stdout,
            stdout = sp.PIPE)
sp.Popen(
            ["lpr"],
            stdin = pr.stdout )
```

where `path` is the filename - opf.pdf. This produces error, in the second `Popen`:

```
0x23f2dd0age specification error:
  pagespecs = [modulo:]spec
  spec      = [-]pageno[@scale][L|R|U|H|V][(xoff,yoff)][,spec|+spec]
                modulo >= 1, 0 <= pageno < modulo
```

(sic). I suspect the `0x23f2dd0` somehow replaced the 'P'. Anyway, I suspect the problem to be in the page spec 1:0@0.8(0.5cm,13.5cm), so I tried with/without the single quotes, and with (escaped) double quotes. I even tried `shlex.quote` which produced a very exotic `''"'"'1:0@0.8(0.5cm,13.5cm)'"'"''`, but still the same error.

What is causing this?

**EDIT** As a last resource, I tried:

```
    os.system(("pdftops -paper A4 -nocenter {} - | "
               "pstops '1:0@0.8(1cm,13.5cm)' | "
               "lpr").format(path))
```

which works perfectly. I'd still prefer the above `Popen` solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what the shell does with that argument (or use something like `printf '%s\n'` to get it to show you).  We need to undo the shell quoting and replace it with Python quoting (which happens to be eerily similar):

```
pr = sp.Popen(
            ["pstops",
             "1:0@0.8(0.5cm,13.5cm)"],
            stdin = ps.stdout,
            stdout = sp.PIPE)
```

Comment: I would bet I tested this before at some point... It seems that each time I decide to use `subprocess` I run into similar problems. Note that in the EDIT above, the single quotes are necessary. Cheers!